# Visual Studio 2015 MSTest - Crashes and not discovering tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, visual-studio-2015

Today I switched from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015 and I am since experiencing problems with running unit tests developed in MSTest. I am working on a solution with 4 projects and 4 test projects, with a total of about 11.000 unit tests.

Now, upon building of the solution and a fresh start of Visual Studio, the IDE usually (not always) discovers all tests. When I try to run them however, I see a lot of error messages in the output window telling me that duplicate tests were found, reducing the number of found tests in the solution.
Then, when the tests are performed, I receive a lot of error notifications telling me about unknown tests having reported a problem and they are therefore ignored.

This leads to the discovered tests rapidly declining, making debugging virtually impossible (since even if a test is found, it is most of the time lost when I let it run in debug mode).

On top of that, Visual Studio 2015 frequently crashes when I try to run one (or many) tests, not giving me any indication about what happened but only the windows "Visual Studio is no longer working" dialog as soon as I click on run.

I'm suspecting the problem is that I have about 10 test classes with each about 400 test methods (which were auto generated), so I just divided them up into each 5 classes with about 80 methods, but that did not change the situation.

I've found the description of the problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560011/vs2015-ctp6-does-not-discover-unit-tests-resharper-does-discover-some-of-them) to be somewhat similar and followed the proposed solution, but this does not work permanently for me.

I'm using ReSharper as an extension in Visual Studio, I don't see the behaviour here.

Comment: If you are seeing consistent crashes, use the "Send a Smile"/"Send A Frown" [feedback](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/content/content.aspx?ContentID=31113).  That allows you to capture a session for reproducing a crash.  I have gotten quite a bit of direct feedback from microsoft when I submitted issues via this mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try that out. I saw improved behaviour when I switched to x64 as test platform, but I still get occassional errors.