# Visual Studio 2015 test explorer doesn't show any test after update

Tags: unit-testing, updates, visual-studio-2015

I updated my Visual Studio Community 2015 (Update 3) and it doesn't show the unit tests of my project at all! I've tried to reinstall VS, it changed nothing, and it also shows we the message "connected services package failed" (and I don't know what it is). And I can't find out how to download an older version of Visual Studio that works, from their idiotic site. I asked the question at their community, nobody answered. Help me! I can't work without tests!!!

Comment: Have the same problem :(

Comment: Tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560011/vs2015-ctp6-does-not-discover-unit-tests-resharper-does-discover-some-of-them but did not help.

Comment: I tried too) no use. I finally found the old version here https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx . Maybe you'll be lucky and they have not still replaced the ISO by the newest. And shut the internet for the installer to prevent it update. But when I downgraded to the oldest version, everything works, but the following message occures: "connected services package failed". It does not hinder to work, but does anyone know what is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue from the new update. As it's having a missing resource DLL. Please follow the steps in this below Microsoft connect link to unblock yourself.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2979953

Comment: Usually I'd recommend to include details of how to solve the issue in the answer, but since this will likely only be a very temporary issue and fixed with the next patch for Visual Studio 2015.3 I guess it's ok.

Comment: I've sloved this problem by downgrading the Visual Studio, but I think I should accept this message as an answer.