# VS2015 doesn't find my NUnit tests

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

As per title, VS2015 just decided that I don't have any tests in my codebase

What I've tried so far:

- restart the machine
- restart VS2015
- clean/rebuild the solution
- reinstall .NET 1.0.0
- Delete the `%TEMP%` folder
- Delete the `AppData/Microsoft/*` folder
- checkout the project again from Git. Tests are working fine on other machines
- Reinstall NUnit 3 Test adapter
- `dotnet restore` command on the command line
- Tried to change the processor architecture in `Test > Test Settings > Default Processor Architecture` with and without a VS2015 restart after it

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you changed your project json?  Could you have accidentally removed your test runner and/or `"dotnet-test-nunit": "3.4.0-beta-3",`

Comment: @Kritner I checked out the project straight from GitHub and on other PCs is working, so no, I didn't change that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Resharper?  If so, it sounds like Resharper has messed up, so I would re-install it.

Comment: Looks very strange - you are posting answer two minutes later after OP answered exactly the same?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy take it easy please! I'm just ranting a little bit after 1 entire day struggling on this stupid problem :-)

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini but you should mark your own answer as correct. You did find the solution on your own. So that's just strange for me

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Resharper did the trick

Shame on Microsoft and shame on that bloated IDE called VS2015

Comment: Resharper is not Microsoft product :) I never had such problems with Code Rush and any Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: It's a plugin for VS2015 so it qualifies as a shameful plugin

Comment: Just wonder why you are blaming Microsoft. Buggy plugins is not their fault

Comment: want an explanation? look at the "solutions" posted here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560011/visual-studio-2015-does-not-discover-unit-tests

Comment: Still no clue. You have re-installed ReSharper and everything started to work. You didn't re-install Visual Studio, did you?