# Visual Studio 2012 doesn't find tests from a project

Tags: testing

I know that this question has been answered here, [Visual Studio 2013 doesn't discover unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304425/visual-studio-2013-doesnt-discover-unit-tests) , and I also have searched at many forums, but after 6 hours, I still haven't found a solution for this.

In a solution with several projects, I have some test classes in almost all projects. Tests are done with the library Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting (10.0) of Microsoft. I also have Resharped installed. Since today I can't execute test methods from a project. The tests of the other class are being executed right, but in one class are not being executed anymore.

If I execute tests with Resharper I get this message error: Inconclusive: Test wasn't run.

If I disable Resharper and execute tests with VS I don't get any message error, but tests don't execute.

I have checked all these solutions but not any of them work:

Disable Resharper
Clear test cache
Remove temp directory from my system drive
Enable/Disable shadow-copy
To check that the directory of the project is not shared.
To delete .suo file from solution

And tests of this .dll not yet work.

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's already solved. It was because Nuget dependency conflicts.