# VS 2015 Test Explorer is empty

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I'm on update 3 with VS2015 and suddenly Test Explorer (for MSTest) doesn't show anything, it's just empty.

[image]

I don't have any extensions installed that relate to unit testing, no NUnit stuff, no Resharper etc. Obviously, solution has been compiled. The same for all solutions with unit tests, they all used to show tests in test explorer but suddenly they all are empty.

What does **not** work:

- Rebooting
- Restarting VS 2015
- Devenv.exe /ResetSettings
- Running a test (by right-clicking on test code)
- Setting Processor Architecture to X64 in Test Settings
- Starting VS in admin mode
- Deleting contents of %LocalAppData%\Micr‌​osoft\VisualStudio\12‌.0\ComponentModelCach‌​e

Anyone have a fix?

pom

Comment: Anything in Output > Show Output From "Tests" ? Does restarting help?

Comment: Yes, output gives output so tests do run, but the test explorer remains empty. Pressing buttons (three arrows) does nothing. Restart won't help.

Comment: Try deleting the content of this folder `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ComponentModelCache` as described here [Visual Studio 2013 doesn't discover unit tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304425/visual-studio-2013-doesnt-discover-unit-tests)

Comment: Sorry, didn't work, good idea though

Comment: Maybe add MSTest.TestAdapter NuGet package to your Test project. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44338786/392184

Answer (score 1):

Please see issue and fix here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2970831. Let us know if this fixed it in your case.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I already solved the issue by re-installing VS 2015 and updates. So I don't know if those instructions would have helped.