# NUnit 3 tests disappear on VS2015

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2015, ui-testing, nunit-3.0

I have a solution with my project for UI tests inside. After clean solution test explorer no longer shows available tests. I've tried several solutions without results:

1. Clean / rebuild in Debug / Release config
2. Reinstall NUnit 3 Test Adapter
3. [Rebuild with different CPU architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304425/visual-studio-2013-doesnt-discover-unit-tests)
4. Restart machine, update VisualStudio and all components to last versions
5. Clean %TEMP%, %LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp
6. Run VS2015 as Administrator

My test environment:

- Windows 8.1 x64
- Visual Studio 2015 Community Update 3
- NUnit 3.4.1.0
- NUnit Test Adapter 3.4.1
- Selenium WebDriver 2.53.1

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. In my project referneces there were several selenium libraries with property "Copy local" = false. Check it, and nunit test adapter found all tests after rebuild.