# Visual Studio 2015 does not discover unit tests: C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, microsoft-cpp-unit-test

I am working on a C++ project and I developed a few test cases. I was able to execute the test cases until suddenly all the test cases disappeared from the test explorer. I mean to say that test methods are not shown in test explorer even though the test project is compiled properly.

I followed the steps given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29560011/3747770) with no success.

These are the things I have done:

- I deleted the content of `%temp%` folder.
- I changed the default Processor Architecture to `X64`. (`Test>Test Settings>Default Processor Architecture>X64`)
- `Restarted` the VS2015.
- `Restarted` the system.
- I tried running `devenv /safemode` (in command prompt), no luck.
- I tried running `devenv /ResetSettings` (in command prompt), no luck.

Notes:

- There is only 1 test project in my solution and it only contains a few tests right now.
- My project files are located on a network drive since I am not allowed to store on local.
- I cannot disable the anti-virus software or firewall and I don't have admin rights on my system.

Comment: Have you tried deleting all files in your %temp%?

Comment: Yes I have tried...

Comment: is it possible to store your tests on the network along with the project files? Typically things seem to work better when they are in the same relative area together. Plus if you were to do it from the network completely, there is perhaps documentation relating to doing your project remotely.

Comment: Have you done a clean solution followed by a rebuild solution?

Comment: Does anything [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304425/visual-studio-2013-doesnt-discover-unit-tests) can help you?

Comment: @Ceros: Have to try couple of steps. But majority of the steps I have tired.

Answer (score 0):

Look into your .vcxproj file and make sure it says

`<ClCompile Include="[your-file-name].cpp" />`

for each of your files.