# Can't reference a project to run unit testing on it

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm runnig through this [walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx) on the Microsoft website. I have gotten up to creating the Unit testing project, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx#Anchor_2). I just cant seem to reference my project.

I right click on references in my Solution Explorer.

[image: Right CLick]

Then I go to solution under the projects tab.

[image: Reference Tab]

If I choose the browse I don't know what to find.

[image: What to find]

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx) was no help. Along with other links that I searched.

I just don't know what to do at this point? What am I supposed to look for when browsing to reference my project?

To answer Ayb4btu  question. My folder looks like this

```
UnitTest //Top folder
    Bank //Bank project to be tested
    BankTest //Bank Unit Test project
```

Comment: when you Browse for reference you have to select .dll file

Comment: Have you got two projects in your solution (the unit test project, and the project to test)?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/29130217/6448640

Comment: @Ayb4btu I have added the folder structure to my question. How do I check if these two projects are in the solution. Isn't that what the reference is going to do?

Comment: @Ashikirsha I tried those things on the answer you gave me but it didn't help. I don't even have a reference to the project.

Comment: @sifavahora Where is the .dll file I need to add? How do I know if I have done it correctly?

Comment: it should be in Bank/bin/Debug/ based on the image 2 that you have posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution file has no projects in it other than your test project. Add the project you want to test to your solution, and then you'll be able to take a project reference on it from your test project.

Do this by right clicking the Solution>Add>Existing Project...