# Getting a conflict with Version numbers while I try to use my Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

**This is the error I'm getting:**

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error Project 'D:\Work\DevWork\ProgrammingProjects\UnitTest\Bank\Bank\Bank.csproj' targets '.NETStandard,Version=v1.4'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'. BankTest

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304425/visual-studio-2013-doesnt-discover-unit-tests?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) post but the solutions didn't work.

I try cleaning the solution then rebuilding the solution and I still get the above error.

Then I've tried cleaning and rebuilding each project. This gives me the above as a warning and an error.

The funny thing is I have run the tests. After cleaning then rebuilding then restarting. I have gotten the test to run once. It is just hit or miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must upgrade your Bank Test Project to .NET Framework 4.6.1, because .Net Standard 1.4 is compatible to .NET Framework 4.6.1.

See [.NET Standard 1.4](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions/netstandard1.4.md) and [.NET implementation support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support)